# .net filestream alternative for python

Tags: python, .net, csv

Good day,

I need equivalent to filestream (fileshare=none,read,write,etc) for python as I need to handle csv file and need while open specific file to disallow shared same file with other same .net filestream
I'm already with use open() function on python but didn't file this paramerter related fileshare

equivalent to filestream (fileshare=none,read,write,etc) in .net languages for python